# Puppeteer gives different results for same test

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, puppeteer

I have a test using jest and puppeteer that checks if a conditional item in a React / material-ui drop down exists or not.

When I run it {headless:true}, it fails every time.
When I run it with {headless:false}, and I initiate the command from the command prompt via `jest --watch` the test fails.
When I then just 'save' the test file (ie: the test watcher notices and runs it) ... the test passes.

The behavior in an actual browser is correct and works fine.

Ideas?

Test code is:

```
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");
const CONSTANTS = require('../../../constants/Config')
const MOCKS = require('../../../test/mocks')
const TEST_CONSTANTS = require('../../../test/testingConstants');

var browser
var page
const apiCall = CONSTANTS.NODE_ENDPOINT + "/api" + '/1234'


describe('Check that reevaluate review section', () => {
    beforeAll(async () => {
        browser = await puppeteer.launch({
            headless: false   
        })
    })
    beforeEach(async () => {
        page = await browser.newPage()

        // Intercept API response and pass mock data for Puppeteer
        await page.setRequestInterception(true);
        page.on('request', request => {
            if (request.url() === apiCall) {
                request.respond({
                    content: 'application/json',
                    headers: { "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*" },
                    body: JSON.stringify({
                        "success": true,
                        "data": MOCKS.requestDataObj_old,
                        "message": "Request 60f78b836a34316bd3ef12ea found"
                    })
                });
            } else {
                request.continue();
            }
        });
        await page.goto(TEST_CONSTANTS.REQUEST_REVIEW_URL + '1234')
    });

    test("reevaluate options include 'Sunset'", async () => {
        await page.waitForSelector('#Request_Section_Reevaluate', { visible: true })
        await page.click('#Request_Section_Reevaluate_ReviewStatus')
        let sunsetElement = await page.waitForSelector('#Request_Section_Reevaluate_ReviewStatus_Optons_MenuItem_Sunset', { visible: true, timeout: 1500 })
        expect(sunsetElement).toBeTruthy()
        page.close()
    })
});
```

Component is a rather large react component down in a rather large react tree... seeing it on the screen would require scrolling down to it and certain aspects only appear after the api call (mocked, above) is called.  The API call is short (and local, so it should be roughly the same time every time) an the timeouts are long  - so I don't think that is the issue.

The error looks like this:

```
 FAIL  src/components/common/RequestSectionReevaluate/RequestSectionReevaluate.ui.test.js (6.668 s)
  Check that reevaluate review section
    × reevaluate options include 'Sunset' (4779 ms)

  ● Check that reevaluate review section › reevaluate options include 'Sunset'

    TimeoutError: waiting for selector `#Request_Section_Reevaluate_ReviewStatus_Optons_MenuItem_Sunset` failed: timeout 1500ms exceeded

      41 |              await page.waitForSelector('#Request_Section_Reevaluate', { visible: true })
      42 |              await page.click('#Request_Section_Reevaluate_ReviewStatus')
    > 43 |              let sunsetElement = await page.waitForSelector('#Request_Section_Reevaluate_ReviewStatus_Optons_MenuItem_Sunset', { visible: true, timeout: 1500 })
         |                                             ^
      44 |              expect(sunsetElement).toBeTruthy()
      45 |              page.close()
      46 |      })

      at new WaitTask (node_modules/puppeteer/src/common/DOMWorld.ts:813:28)
      at DOMWorld.waitForSelectorInPage (node_modules/puppeteer/src/common/DOMWorld.ts:656:22)
      at Object.internalHandler.waitFor (node_modules/puppeteer/src/common/QueryHandler.ts:78:19)
      at DOMWorld.waitForSelector (node_modules/puppeteer/src/common/DOMWorld.ts:511:25)
      at Frame.waitForSelector (node_modules/puppeteer/src/common/FrameManager.ts:1290:47)
      at Page.waitForSelector (node_modules/puppeteer/src/common/Page.ts:3222:29)
      at _callee3$ (src/components/common/RequestSectionReevaluate/RequestSectionReevaluate.ui.test.js:43:34)
      at tryCatch (node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/regeneratorRuntime.js:86:17)
      at Generator._invoke (node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/regeneratorRuntime.js:66:24)
      at Generator.next (node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/regeneratorRuntime.js:117:21)
      at asyncGeneratorStep (node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/asyncToGenerator.js:3:24)
      at _next (node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/asyncToGenerator.js:25:9)

A worker process has failed to exit gracefully and has been force exited. This is likely caused by tests leaking due to improper teardown. Try running with --detectOpenHandles to find leaks.
Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       1 failed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        8.474 s
```

Comment: I assume you've tried increasing the timeout just to be sure? And you dumped `page.content()` to verify that the element is on the page?

Comment: I have increased the timeouts, yes.

I did not know about page.content() but I will take a look asap.

Comment: Bah, good point, I added additional content after some trouble shooting...  I'll just revert the edit so it's not confusing.